# Не получается вызвать функцию

Tags: jquery, функции

Изучаю jQuery, хочу написать скрипт валидации полей формы, [вот такой скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/S7224/45/), но не работает, потому что функция не вызывается, как я понимаю. 
Как его правильно вызывать чтобы работало?

Comment: Она вызывается, но только одby раз после загрузки страницы. А вам надо её вызывать по какому-то событию: или keyup, или blur, или другому на ваше усмотрение.

P.S. Не особо вдавая в подробности - вот [как это может быть реализованно][1]. Хотя такие вещи лучше всего [оформлять в виде плагинов][2].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/S7224/46/
   [2]:http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_jQuery

Comment: @Deonis спасибо)